# jQuery: Wait/Delay 1 second without executing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, wait, seconds

I can't get the `.delay` method working in jQuery:

```
$.delay(3000); // not working
$(queue).delay(3000); // not working
```

I'm using a while loop to wait until an uncontrolled changing value is greater than or equal to another and I can't find any way to hault execution for X seconds.

Comment: try using setTimeout in the callback

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: that is not what the delay function is designed for, it is designed for use between queued jquery events (like fade().delay().show()). You need the setTimeOut function.

Comment: @JoJa: You are correct on the main point, however the no argument form of show (and hide) do not use the effects queue.

Comment: Please, state what you are trying to achieve with the delay. All JavaScript executes on a single thread, and freezing it for X seconds may cause adverse user experience.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

$.delay is used to delay animations in a queue, not halt execution.

Instead of using a while loop, you need to recursively call a method that performs the check every second using `setTimeout`:

```
var check = function(){
    if(condition){
        // run when condition is met
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(check, 1000); // check again in a second
    }
}

check();
```

Comment: I think, setTimeout is enough.

Comment: Your the bomb bro, this is exactly what I needed to fix my code.

Comment: @Jiemurat and anyone else in the future: setTimeout doesn't break the flow of execution.
The great code of Niessner obtain this untile the conditions became true!

Comment: If you don't need to break the flow of execution, you can simply use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: i always get "check is not a function", my check function has two parameters though

Comment: If you want your code to work as soon as the condition is met, `setTimeout(check,0);`

Answer (score 281):

You can also just delay some operation this way:

```
setTimeout(function (){
  
  // Something you want delayed.
            
}, 5000); // How long you want the delay to be, measured in milliseconds.
```

Comment: Just an FYI, this doesn't break the flow of execution, so if you need to "stop everything" for a few seconds, you're going to need something like what Niessner has posted.

Comment: Yes... its a callback to the function and does not block. Thanks for the answer, it fixed my issue.

Comment: if the frequency is extremely short and we expect this function to be running forever, will it eventually blow the stack?

Answer (score 39):

**ES6 setTimeout**

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("we waited 204586560000 ms to run this code, oh boy wowwoowee!");
}, 204586560000);
```

Edit: 204586560000 ms is the approximate time between the original question and this answer... assuming I calculated correctly.

Comment: really nice using the approximate time from the original question to this answer

Answer (score 24):

If you are using ES6 features and you're in an async function, you can effectively halt the code execution for a certain time with this function:

```
const delay = millis => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(_ => resolve(), millis)
});
```

This is how you use it:

```
await delay(5000);
```

It will stall for the requested amount of milliseconds, but *only if you're in an async function*. Example below:

```
const myFunction = async function() {
  // first code block ...

  await delay(5000);

  // some more code, executed 5 seconds after the first code block finishes
}
```

Comment: I solved this problem a similar way in an async function by simply doing the following:
`await setTimeout(_ => {}, millis);`
then moving to the next line.

Comment: await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

Answer (score 10):

jQuery's `delay` function is meant to be used with effects and effect queues, see the [`delay` docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and the example therein:

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

If you want to observe a variable for changes, you could do something like

```
(function() {
    var observerInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (/* check for changes here */) {
           clearInterval(observerInterval);
           // do something here
        }
    }, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: setInterval has a second mandatory parameter, the time in milliseconds ;)

Comment: Thanks @sara.potyscki, fixed.

Comment: @JulianD. Thank you for this suggestion. I landed on this question while googling for a solution.  This is exactly what I needed for my project.

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript `setTimeout` is a very good solution:

```
function funcx()
   {
   // your code here
   // break out here if needed
   setTimeout(funcx, 3000);
   }

funcx();
```

The `delay` function in jQuery is mostly used for delaying animations in a jQuery animation queue.

Answer (score 7):

`delay()` doesn't halt the flow of code then re-run it. There's no practical way to do that in JavaScript. Everything has to be done with functions which take callbacks such as `setTimeout` which others have mentioned.

The purpose of jQuery's `delay()` is to make an animation queue wait before executing. So for example `$(element).delay(3000).fadeIn(250);` will make the element fade in after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

```
    function sleep(num) {
        let now = new Date();
        let stop = now.getTime() + num;
        while(true) {
            now = new Date();
            if(now.getTime() > stop) return;
        }
    }

    sleep(1000);   // 1 second 
    alert('here');
```

It gets the current time in milliseconds, adds `num` (which is a future time) where you've adding `num` many milliseconds to the current time.

An infinite while loop starts up checking the current time until the current time is later than the time we specified in the previous paragraph, once that has occurred the function stops running and execution continues to what ever is after this function call.

Comment: Please provide some information about the answer so that future readers get more information from your answer.

Comment: this approach uses CPU extremely hard, such sleep might cause the freeze of the webpage and users will not like it. Don't use it.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript is an asynchronous programming language so you can't stop the execution for a of time; the only way you can [pseudo]stop an execution is using `setTimeout()` that is not a delay but a "delayed function callback".

Comment: ...and in case you are interested in this "sleep" use of `setTimeout()`, you might want to take a look to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/7658051

Answer (score 4):

Only javascript It will work without jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function sleep(miliseconds) {
                var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
                }
            }

            function hello() {
                sleep(5000);
                alert('Hello');
            }
            function hi() {
                sleep(10000);
                alert('Hi');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="hello();">Say me hello after 5 seconds </a>
        <br>
        <a href="#" onclick="hi();">Say me hi after 10 seconds </a>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looping to wait in javascript is a bad idea! All javascript functionality will **stop** while the loop is running. This will have unanticipated side-effects. It's much better to use non-blocking functions like setTimeout().