# Delay the disabling of an element?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery how could you go about disabling a button and have it re-enable after a few seconds?

I've tried using a .delay(###).attr and .removeattr, but I can't get it to work. From what I've read this is due to .delay made for animations and instead I need to use fadeout?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8896368/1220302. You'll want to use setTimeout(function() {}, [milliseconds])

Comment: `delay` is a queue operation and does only work with CSS animations.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $btn =  $('input[type="button"]'),
    aFewSeconds = 3000;

$btn.prop({ disabled: true });

setTimeout(function(){
    $btn.prop({ disabled: false});
}, aFewSeconds);
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html). Here's a button that will be disabled for a second when clicked, although anything could be used to invoke this action:

**HTML**

```html
<button class='tempDisable'>Click Me</button>
```

**JavaScript** *(wrapped in ready function)*

```js
$(".tempDisable").click(function () {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function (el) {
        $(el).prop("disabled", false);
    }, 1000, this);
});
```

## See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/q5Scg/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will resolve your problem, but try using `$elem.attr('disabled', true)` to disable, `$elem.attr('disabled', false)` to enable again. Some reason `$elem.removeAttr('disabled')` can be unreliable.

`.delay()` shouldn't be a problem though, please post your code.