# For Loop Delay Without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

So, here's my problem... I've got a for loop inside a function

```
var fan1 = function () {
for(var i=0; i<flare1base.length; i++) {            
    for(var i=0; i<200; i++)
        flare1base.rotation.z += 0.01;
    };
};
```

It should do essentially that, fairly simple, but... I need it to wait 10 milliseconds before adding to the rotation again. The problem is I don't think I can use setTimeout or just use setInterval instead of the entire for loop, because it's acting on an object in an array, and if I do

```
f1 = setInterval("flare1array[i].rotation.z += 0.01",10);
setTimeout("clearInterval(f1)",2000);
```

It queues up an action to do rotate the thingy, but by the time the action occurs the for loop has gone around again and "i" is different.

Comment: Why do you have 2 for loops? Also, the use of `i` in both will screw things up. And why not just use 1 loop with `i < flare1base.length * 200`?

Comment: I think it's flare1base[i].rotation.z += 0.01 where i is the outer i

Comment: I have two for loops because... the first (outer) for loop is what I use to make sure the following runs for every item in the array.
The second (inner) for loop is what I'm attempting to use to replace the setInterval and setTimeout stuff that I have, since I can't use setInterval inside a for loop since by the time the interval executes, "i" has changed.

Comment: First problem I see is you reuse `i`.  Should have `k` or `j` for the inner loop so it doesn't change on you.

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery: Wait/Delay 1 second without executing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896327/jquery-wait-delay-1-second-without-executing-code)

Have you tried:

```
setTimeout(function (){

         flare1array[i].rotation.z += 0.01;

         }, 10);
```

Comment: I admit, I've not tried that specifically, but... again, that would replace the inner (second) for loop I have, but it would still be inside of the outer (first) for loop, so... still back at the problem of not being able to use setTimeout or setInterval inside a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `setInterval` and then `clearInterval`? You could do something like this:

```
function rotate(max) {            
    var i = 0;
    return function () {
        flare1base.rotation.z += 0.01;         
        if (++i == max) clearInterval(id);        
    }
}

var id = setInterval(rotate(200), 10);
```

[Similar example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KeeA/)

`setInterval` returns an `id` that can later be passed to `clearInterval` to prevent the action from continuing indefinitely. Here I've wrapped a counter variable `i` in a closure, which keeps track of how many times the inner function has been called. When it has been called `max` times, it stops.

By the way, if you know what the starting value of `flare1base.rotation.z` is, it would be better to calculate it afresh each time the function is called rather than continuously adding `0.01`, as the result of repeated floating point additions may be imprecise. For example, if you know it starts at, you could do `flare1base.rotation.z = 0.01 * ++i;` (and remove the increment from the `if` statement).

To extend this to an array of items, you can wrap the whole process in a loop. Assuming that your items are in an array `arr`:

```
function rotate(arr, idx, max) {    
    var i = 0;
    return function () {
        arr[idx] += 0.01;         
        if (++i == max) clearInterval(ids[idx]);        
    }
}

var ids = new Array(5);    
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {    
    ids[i] = setInterval(rotate(arr, i, 200), 10);
}
```

[updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KeeA/1/)

Comment: I could do that, but... again, that doesn't solve the problem of repeating an action, whether it's using a for statement or setInerval, inside of a for loop. Basically I need to do something a certain number of times with a certain amount of time between repetitions, only I don't need to do it once, I need to do that for each item in an array.

Comment: @JupiterFlux Please see my update which shows how you could apply the same principle to an array of items.

Comment: @JupiterFlux does this still not do what you want?