# Function to scroll a page down until certain content is reached

Tags: jquery, while-loop, menu, infinite-scroll

I am working on a paginated infinite scroll page. In the menu I am making a button that triggers a function which scrolls down (100px at a time) until certain content (page3.html) is loaded.

```
function GOindex() {
while (urllist.includes('page3.html') == false) {
var y = $(window).scrollTop(); 
$(window).scrollTop(y+100);
};
}
```

New pages are loaded at the moment the end of the page is reached. The html addresses of the new pages are appended in urllist. I am using a while loop to scroll down until page3.html appears in the urllist.

Unfortunately the script gets stuck when I press the button. I think this is because the while loop is too fast and multiple scroll events are triggered on top of each other.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work like this:

```
function GOindex() {
if (urllist.includes('page3.html') == false) {
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
  $(window).scrollTop(y+100);
  console.log("100 down");
  setTimeout(GOindex, 1);
 }
 else {
  console.log("page3.html loaded, stop scrolling");
 }
};
```

Found the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896327/jquery-wait-delay-1-second-without-executing-code) question. It might not be super elegant in my case but it works well! Basically it is better to use an if statement and loop the function with a timeout.