# How can I slowly display a message character by character using setIterval?

Tags: javascript

FYI--- I read the duplicate to this question and got nowhere.

I Have a website up on fire base [here](https://final-project-phase-1.firebaseapp.com/) and if you see there's a button div that reads "See what I can do" I want to to display that message one character at a time. I immediately thought of using a for loop and str.substr() as well as an interval. This is all my brain could muster

```
const msg = "See What I can do";

function displayMsg(msg) {
    let newMsg = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < msg.length + 1; i++) {
         console.log(msg.substr(0, i));
    }
}

setInterval(displayMsg(msg), 1000);
```

doesn't work because it just runs through the whole loop. How can I make it stop and wait 1s every iteration? Is there a more popular approach to this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Wait/Delay 1 second without executing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896327/jquery-wait-delay-1-second-without-executing-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each index `i` of the message, you can set a timeout to run after `i * 1000` ms which will append to (or replace) the existing text:

```js
const msg = "See What I can do";
for (let i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    target.textContent += msg[i];
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Another option, with `await`:

```js
(async () => {
  const msg = "See What I can do";
  for (const char of msg) {
    target.textContent += char;
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! are these methods the ones typically used when using that dynamic typing effect you see on all these websites?

Comment: I don't know which websites you're referring to, but there are multiple ways to achieve it, these are only 2 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive function does the trick:

```js
function typeOn (message, container, interval = 200) {
  // split the first character and the remainder of the message
  const [c, ...rest] = message;

  // append the character
  container.innerHTML += c;

  // if there's anything left do it again after a delay
  if (rest.length) {
    setTimeout(() => typeOn(rest, container, interval), interval);
  }
}

// find the element you want to type into
const el = document.querySelector('div');

// pass in the text, the element, and (optional) speed
typeOn('Wookies and hats and bananas, oh my!', el, 100);
```

```html
<div></div>
```